# SSE: why, technically, is 16-aligned data faster to move?

Tags: sse, simd, memory-alignment

Is it a bus architecture issue?    How is it circumvented in i7?

I'm aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14823568/89706),  I just don't think it answers the real *why*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Relationship between SSE vectorization and Memory alignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14823482/relationship-between-sse-vectorization-and-memory-alignment)

Comment: I'm curious about the.downvote and marking as duplicate - of the question I linked to myself.  As the discussion below (I hope) shows, there's much more to be said beyond what was accepted there as an answer.

Comment: Did you read the comments on the accepted answer, particularly the last one ?

Comment: I read it with care.  I understand that some people accept 'hardware design involves compromises' as an answer - but I don't understand why downvote a question intended to dig deeper.  I wish to understand the specific compromise taken here, and not leave it as a general 'it's a tradeoff thing'.

Comment: Well the question is not only a (possible) duplicate, but it's also a candidate for closure both for being "too broad" (it's a big subject) and also for being off-topic (SO questions should be about *a specific programming-related problem that you face*, not general discussion about e.g. computer architecture). Try Google or some general reading on the basics of memory architecture etc, and if you have a *specific* programming-related question then come back and ask it. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for details about asking on-topic questions.

Comment: As my previous comment notes, this question was asked because the so-called duplicate was not specific *enough*, and I didn't see any suggestions on closing that one because it was too broad.    I believe this one clearly qualifies as specific, programming related question.

Comment: Fine - you're entitled to your opinion, but I don't see a specific programming-related question here. This is why we have a voting system though, and I'm happy to be proved wrong in due course if the question gets up-votes from others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The processor is built to work with data of certain sizes and alignments. When you use data outside of those sizes and alignments, you effectively need to shift it into alignment, crop it, compute on it using the normal instructions, then shift it back into place.

Comment: *How* is a processor built to work with certain alignments? The register doesn't care where he got its data from. Neither do the ALU's that operate on it.

Comment: @OfekShilon Registers and ALU's don't know anything about alignment. It's the memory subsystem that cares. The reason why aligned is faster is simply because it is harder to build for misalignment. For example, a misaligned load can cover two cachelines, therefore you will need to fetch both, and then extract out the parts you want and shift/blend them together.

Comment: @Mystical - thanks, I suspected something along these lines. So why is it harder to fetch memory at a non aligned address?   Is the system bus limited to fetch only aligned addresses for some reason?  Is it a memory controller thing?   May it's something in the cache associativity (address 'aliasing') implementation?